# jQuery change image after hovering a dynamic link

Tags: php, jquery, mouseover

So I generate a list of names that got an image linked in the database.
I will put the names in an HTML list. Now I got 1 div that should contain the image linked to the name, so as soon as I hover an other link; the image should change.

These links are generated by PHP and can be either 1 or 100 links.

I got the following HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="divid_1"></div>
```

As soon I hover over link 1; I want the corresponding image to be shown, same for link 2 and so on.

Thanks.

Comment: You do realize this means the image is loaded when you hover the mouse? So users will see a 'flash'. That's not pretty. **edit** What I mean is: the images aren't preloaded.

Comment: Agree. Probably you should better load preview on click rather than full image on mouseover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try :

```
$("ul li").mouseover(function() {
    $("#divid_1").find("img").attr("src",$(this).find("a").attr("href"));
});
```

You must add an `<img>` in your `div#divid_1` for this to work.

[See jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/kreaus/cKJqq/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="divid_1"><img id='img'></div>
```

JS:

```
$('ul > li > a').hover(function() { $('#img').src = $(this).attr('href'); })
```

I didn't try, but should work